# PayPal REST API: get Web Profile ID – 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, guzzle, guzzle6

I've got a problem with the PayPal REST API or at least I am getting an error back using Guzzle as client.

The PHP code:

```
$body = [
    'name' => 'TestName982365923',
    'presentation' => [
        'brand_name'  => 'Test Name',
        'logo_image'  => 'https://example.com/site/static/public/img/paypal-logo.png',
        'locale_code' => 'DE',
    ],
];

$body_json = json_encode($body);


// New HTTP client
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => $this->getApiBaseUrl(),
    'debug' => true
]);

$options = [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type'    => 'application/json',
        'Authorization'   => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
    ],
    'body'    => $body_json,
];


try {
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'payment-experience/web-profiles/', $options);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $this->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Returns:

> - Trying 173.0.93.199:443...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.93.199) port 443 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem CApath: none
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
> - ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
> - start date: Feb 7 00:00:00 2022 GMT
> - expire date: Mar 10 23:59:59 2023 GMT
> - subjectAltName: host "api.sandbox.paypal.com" matched cert's "api.sandbox.paypal.com"
> - issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
> - SSL certificate verify ok. > GET /v1/payment-experience/web-profile HTTP/1.1 Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.5
>   curl/7.68.0 PHP/7.4.16 Content-Type: application/json Authorization:
>   Bearer AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQ
> - Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found < Content-Type: application/json < Content-Length: 131 < Connection:
>   keep-alive < Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 12:49:23 GMT < Application_id:
>   APP-80W284485P519543T < Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store,
>   must-revalidate < Caller_acct_num: AK28QXXXULZL < Paypal-Debug-Id:
>   9e6XXXXe67ed9 < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
>   includeSubDomains <
> - Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>   {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"ba3XXXXX2d6","message":"Invalid
>   request - see details","information_link":"http (truncated...)

When I put the same request into Paw (similar to Postman) I am getting a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" back … with a "Webprofile ID". So I guess the problem is not my code itself, but Guzzle or my local MAMP? Is that part the main reason?

> Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Guzzle 6.5
PHP 7.4.16 (curl: HTTP2 enabled)
Apache 2.4.46
Local dev is using https

Comment: `"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"ba3XXXXX2d6","message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"http (truncated...)` What is the full HTTP response body?

Comment: The "truncated"? I don't know, it is not in the actual message itself. IIRC this is for paypal support only!?

Comment: An interesting approach to ask for support with a problem and not include the relevant error information

Comment: If you are not able to log the actual HTTP response body from your environment for some reason, use some other testing tool such as `curl`